# What's the name of this syntax? (named arrays?)

Tags: javascript

A few minutes ago, i met with this:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 6];
var [two, four, eight, twelve] = array.map(num => num * 2);
console.log(four) // 4
```

Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: `map()` returns an array. The assignment to an array like this is called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: take alook at [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Also, check out [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212).